# How to handle all error conditions on success or failure reponse

Tags: javascript, json, response

I'm working on a screen where I sent a request and I get response in two types.
One is **success** and contains the below format -

```
{
    "searchNames": [
        {
            "CustomerName": "John",
            "CustomerType": "Business",
            "Profession": "Businessman",
            "address": {
                "address1": null,
                "address2": null,
                "city": null,
                "state": null,
                "country": null
            },
            "ContactNumber": null
        }
    ],
    "Count": 0
}
```

The other is failure response and the format differently everytime, there can be no error code or message in the format.

```
{
status: "FAILURE"
error: {
errorMsg: [1]
0:  {
fieldName: "CustomerName"
errorCode: null
message: ""
}
errorNo: 12
}
}
```

I have tried validating the response and displaying the response, but I have no idea whether it is the right way to do the same.

```
function result(response)
{
if(response.searchNames)
{
console.log("result", response.searchNames );
}
else
                          {
                            var errorString = ["Error : Invalid Data"];
                              if (response.status && response.status.toLowerCase() ===
                                  'failure' && response.error && response.error.errorMsg &&
                                  response.error.errorMsg.length > 0) {
                                  var errorString = [];
                                  for (var errMsg in response.error.errorMsg) {
                                      errorString.push(response.error.errorMsg[
                                          errMsg].message);
                                  }
}
```

My questions are -

1. Is it the right way to do the error validations. Or are there any best practices for this. **The error response may or may not contain error message. If there is error message, I should show the error message, otherwise I should show the default error message stored in another variable.**
2. In the success response as well is it the right way to check the success response.
   What is the right way in handling all the conditions and how to do it.

Comment: what is `result()` where you call it ? if it is xhr why not just setup failure handlers ?

Comment: Hi eicto, I just gave that simply. Actually the above function will be used in a promise after then()

Comment: i think your question is to general and probably "best practices"...  Answer then - it   mainly depends on your API data... (try something like JSON schema)

Comment: I did not get you. I want to know whether, what I have handled is right or wrong. Or should I add some more conditions for handling errors. Can you tell me is it the right way on what I have done

Comment: I don't know your api... for thing you described it is enough, may be to check if errorMsg is array... do you have a problem with this code ?

Comment: No @eicto, I'm not satisfied with what I wrote and feel something is wrong.  Can you see this

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/